# Shortcut to rundll32 with hidden input

Tags: windows, command-line, virus, shortcuts

I came across a Windows 7 that - when a USB stick is inserted - shows the USB stick in My Computer but the folder simply contains a shortcut. Upon accessing the shortcut the actual content is presented.

The shortcut looks something like this:

`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c start rundll32  \abc.abc,ABcPrS`

The `abc` part is a 60 character string in `[a-f]` range; the two parts are identical (before the dot and after the dot); I'm not posting the actual string as it might be a security issue.

The `ABcPrS` is a 16-character string with upper and lower letters in `[a-zA-Z]` range. This looks like a password to me.

What is this thing? The backslash suggests some (base64) encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of this tool is to run a certain part of a DLL file as if it were a regular executable.

The first parameter to rundll32 is a file name and function name (separated by a comma). So it means "load the DLL file `\abc.abc` (yes, that backslash is just part of a file path) and run function `ABcPrS` in it". (If more text is provided after a space, would be passed as a single textual parameter to that function.)

Neither the file name nor function name are encoded in any way. In your case it literally has a randomly generated name, as one would expect from a virus.

And yes, a mysterious shortcut that runs a mysterious file with a random name means **your USB stick is infected.** (The real files might still be there in a hidden folder, though.)

Comment: Followup: I'm just a bit confused about the linux-like \ path. Where does this point in the file system? Does \ resolve to `%HOMEDRIVE%` or `%SystemDrive%` or something along those lines? Using `dir \` would suggest this.

Comment: It's not "linux-like" in any way. The leading \ just means "root of the current drive" (which varies depending on the process' idea of "current directory").